# Visual Studio 2017 outputting older build versions in bin/debug folder

Tags: c#, debugging, build, visual-studio-2017, bin

When I build a C# program (this has been going on for several different solutions/projects I have been working on) in Visual Studio 2017, the new, updated code will build and run in debug mode (and run correctly).

However, the *application* that Visual Studio has been outputting when I build/debug them has been remaining with the original, first version of code that I saved. When I choose the options to rebuild, it will update the time stamp on the application and `.pdb` files, but the application will perform the way it did in earlier code versions, not the most recent code version that was running problem when I ran debug mode immediately after pressing Ctrl + F5.

These are C# Console Apps with the .NET Framework 4.6.1, if that makes any difference. I checked the output folder, and it is indeed the desired folder and the one I have been looking in... so why is the time stamp updating on the application (`.exe` file) that it outputs, but not the code itself? What am I missing?

Comment: Like Josh's suggestion, you could clean and rebuild your solution/project, view the result. Actually if you just build your solution directly, maybe you would get the out-to date information which means that the update was not saved to your output dll file.

Comment: What about this issue? Would you please share us the latest information? Do you resolved it after you clean and rebuild your solution/projects?

Comment: It seems to be working now, but I'm not sure what I did differently.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. I just add the possible reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into strange things like this in Visual Studio, the first thing that usually works is to clean the project and rebuild. If that doesn't work, I'll close Visual Studio, re-launch, then clean and rebuild again. If that doesn't work, I would start looking into any extensions you have installed that might be getting in the way of your build process.

Further, you can look into logging the extensions activity to help troubleshoot if there are issue there. See the following article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-extensions-with-the-activity-log/

You may have already tried this, but since it wasn't mentioned I thought I'd provide it for others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

(1) Your project was not recompiled during debugging. Please enable Edit and Continue under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

(2) Visual Studio has a concept of incremental build. If you have a solution with two or much more projects and if you change source code in only one of the two projects, the "Build" command will compile only the modified project. But the "Rebuild" command, on the other hand, it will recompile all projects in this solution.